# DNS BIND on CENTOS 6.3 and domain nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind, nameserver

I am somewhat new in BIND and DNS, so please tolerate my stupid Questions.
I having problem running my own custom nameserver. I have a virtual hosting with openVZ (CENTOS 6.3), with 3 IP addresses and also a domain name.

I can't ping my domain name (example.com) from outside, and intodns diagonised following errors.

**http://www.intodns.com/example.com**

```
    Mismatched NS records   WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.
    DNS servers responded   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
66.215.210.17 66.215.210.19 66.215.210.18
    Name of nameservers are valid   OK. The nameservers reported by the parent send out nothing as shown above. I can't check nothing so it's a green!
    Multiple Nameservers    ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.
    Nameservers are lame    OK. All the nameservers listed at the parent servers answer authoritatively for your domain.
    Missing nameservers reported by parent  OK. All NS records are the same at the parent and at your nameservers.
    Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers    You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again: 

ns1.example.com. 
ns2.example.com. 
ns3.example.com.
```

**My domain (example.com) setting:**

```
example.com nameservers
ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com
ns3.example.com
```

**# uname -a**

> Linux server1.example.com 2.6.32-042stab072.10 #1 SMP Wed Jan 16 18:54:05 MSK 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**# cat /etc/named.conf**

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 66.215.210.17;};
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "example.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "/var/named/example.com.hosts";
        };
```

**# cat /var/named/example.com.hosts**

```
$ttl 38400
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. webmaster.example.com. (
                        2013022401
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )

        IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
        IN      NS      ns3.example.com.

        IN      MX      10      mail.example.com.

ns1     IN      A       66.215.210.17
ns2     IN      A       66.215.210.18
ns3     IN      A       66.215.210.19

example.com.     IN      A 66.215.210.17

www     IN      CNAME   example.com.
mail    IN      CNAME   example.com.
```

**service named status**

```
version: 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.6
CPUs found: 4
worker threads: 4
number of zones: 20
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is OFF
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
named (pid  21130) is running...
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 66.215.210.17
nameserver 66.215.210.18
nameserver 66.215.210.19
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

**# host 66.215.210.17**

```
17.210.215.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer unknown.hostforweb.net.
```

**# nslookup ns1.example.com**

```
Server:         66.215.210.17
Address:        66.215.210.17#53

Name:   ns1.example.com
Address: 66.215.210.17
```

**# dig example.com**

```
; > DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.6 > example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34794
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.             38400   IN      A       66.215.210.17

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.             38400   IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
example.com.             38400   IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
example.com.             38400   IN      NS      ns3.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.example.com.         38400   IN      A       66.215.210.17
ns2.example.com.         38400   IN      A       66.215.210.18
ns3.example.com.         38400   IN      A       66.215.210.19

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 66.215.210.17#53(66.215.210.17)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 26 22:47:59 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 146
```

**# ifconfig**

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:45964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4545207 (4.3 MiB)  TX bytes:4545207 (4.3 MiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:313568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:329176 errors:0 dropped:888 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:53252985 (50.7 MiB)  TX bytes:60679739 (57.8 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:66.215.210.17  P-t-P:66.215.210.17  Bcast:66.215.210.17  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:66.215.210.18  P-t-P:66.215.210.18  Bcast:66.215.210.18  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:2  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:66.215.210.19  P-t-P:66.215.210.19  Bcast:66.215.210.19  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

I have edited the domain name and IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration file sets

```
allow-query     { localhost; };
```

That means BIND will only respond to queries from it's own server.

```
[jonv@desk ~]$ dig @66.215.210.17 example.com. soa

; <<>> DiG 9.7.6-P1 <<>> @66.215.210.17 example.com. soa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 59075
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
```

The 'status: REFUSED' is the big indicator of what's wrong.

Edit:  You should be able to just remove the line, the default is allow-query {any;};. Without understanding your environment further, it's hard to give you an exact answer. You can also put the allow-query line within the zone statement for example.com while leaving the allow-query { localhost;}; in place for the global setting.

Comment: allow-query     { localhost; };
That means BIND will only respond to queries from it's own server.
Then how should it be, so that its opened, Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: Thanks a lot, after adding allow-query {any;}; its working, for 3 days I am looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the Dns record.
Then create a new Dns record. 
This just worked for me.