# Network not working after fiddling with webmin

Tags: networking, routing

Can some please help me restore my networking, I have a VPS CENTOS6.3. Few minutes before it is working well, accept i can't connect to Yum repository. So I thought i can change some settings in Hostname and DNS Cleint under webmins network configuration. I  changed the nameserver IP order (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 66.215.210.17) and also I have removed routing and gateways IP (* more later). Now I can't connect from terminal.

Few minutes back: *(from treminal using putty)*
**# host 66.215.210.17**

```
17.210.215.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer unknown.hostforweb.net.
```

Now *(only from hosting VPS java client console)*
**# host 66.215.210.17**

```
Host 17.210.215.66.in-addr.arpa not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

- I have removed routing and gateways IP, because the IP 17.210.215.66 there was, I remember changing by myself from 0.0.0.0, earlier. Instead of putting back 0.0.0.0 I left it empty and applied the change. My Bad!

How can reset it back

**Follow up info:**

Webmin last 2 log entries before it went down

```
1362078063.15514.0 [28/Feb/2013 22:01:03] root 5b3f3abda88f002b2e8a0f2f55a4166e 94.82.102.237 net save_dns.cgi "dns" "-" "-" domain='' domain_def='1' hostname='server1.example.com' hosts='1' nameserver_0='8.8.8.8' nameserver_1='8.8.4.4' 
nameserver_2='66.215.210.17' nameserver_3='66.215.210.18' nameserver_4='66.215.210.19' nameserver_5='' order_0='files' order_1='dns' order_2='' order_3=''

1362078078.15547.0 [28/Feb/2013 22:01:18] root 5b3f3abda88f002b2e8a0f2f55a4166e 94.82.102.237 net save_routes.cgi "routes" "-" "-" dev_0='' forward='0' gateway0='' 
gateway1='' gateway60='' gateway61='' gatewaydev0='' gatewaydev1='' gw_0='' ldev_0='' lnet_0='' lnetmask_0='' net_0='' netmask_0=''
```

**more info about my machine**
[DNS BIND on CENTOS 6.3 and domain nameservers](https://serverfault.com/questions/482747/dns-bind-on-centos-6-3-and-domain-nameservers)

Comment: Please provide the output of `ip route` and the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Comment: **/etc/sysconfig/network** gives -bash: /etc/sysconfig/network: Permission denied

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**
-bash: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0: No such file or directory

You'll find more info about my machine here 
[link]http://serverfault.com/questions/482747/dns-bind-on-centos-6-3-and-domain-nameservers[link]

Comment: What about `ip route`?

Comment: **ip route**
169.254.0.0/16 dev venet0  scope link  metric 1002

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed the default gateway of your server.

Start digging around the subfolders of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` and `cat`'ing file you see there. One of them probably has a `GATEWAY=` entry in it.

Once you find out what your gateway should be, add the route as follows, replacing *interface* with the name of the interface from the config file you found:

> ip route add default via *interface*

Alternatively, ask your host what your default gateway should be.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by doing

```
# route add default gw 66.215.210.17
```

Found this link http://bit.ly/PPBF9l